# Evoke change with jQuery event

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery I want to make a change on the `<h1>` when user clicks button.

```
$('.button').on('click', function{colorchange(this)})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ytCC/1/

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will only work on chrome as you are using webkit animation.

This is the solution. get(0) is used to get first h1 because jquery return nodes list.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        colorchange($("h1").get(0));
    });
});
```

Comment: After a quick edit to the colorchange function to accept arrays this solves my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle works for me, but you should close the h1-tag with an < /h1>, not with an < /h2>. 
The code above should do what?

Are you looking for something like
`$('.title').on('click', function{colorchange(this)});`